# Should I use "the" before "same" in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Which one of these sentences is correct?

> Different instances of a class have different values for the instance variables of the class, but the values of the static variables are same for every instance of the class.

and

> Different instances of a class have different values for the instance variables of the class, but the values of the static variables are **the** same for every instance of the class.

Comment: Look at the usage note at [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/same).

Comment: Better yet, just look at all the examples. _same_ is almost always preceded by _the_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use *the same*. The only time *same* is usually used without *the* is when it's being used as a pronoun, and this tends to be used only in certain contexts, such as business jargon:

> if you send us your order for the materials, we will deliver same tomorrow

When used as an adjective or adverb, it's almost always used in the set phrase *the same*. See all the examples in [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/same)